# How to delete a "0%" label from an horizontal bar plot

Tags: r, plotly

On this horizontal bar chart I am trying not to show the 0%, I have tried a lot and I am stuck.

[image: The picture]

```
library(plotly)

y <- c('The course was effectively<br>organized',
       'The course developed my<br>abilities and skills for<br>the subject',
       'The course developed my<br>ability to think critically about<br>the subject',
       'I would recommend this<br>course to a friend')
x1 <- c(0, 24, 27, 29)
x2 <-c(30, 0, 26, 24)
x3 <- c(21, 19, 0, 15)
x4 <- c(16, 15, 11, 0)
x5 <- c(12, 11, 13, 0)

data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

top_labels <- c('Strongly<br>agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly<br>disagree')

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x1, y = ~y, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
               marker = list(color = 'rgba(38, 24, 74, 0.8)',
                             line = list(color = 'rgb(248, 248, 249)', width = 1))) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x2, marker = list(color = 'rgba(71, 58, 131, 0.8)')) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x3, marker = list(color = 'rgba(122, 120, 168, 0.8)')) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x4, marker = list(color = 'rgba(164, 163, 204, 0.85)')) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x5, marker = list(color = 'rgba(190, 192, 213, 1)')) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = "",
                                   showgrid = FALSE,
                                   showline = FALSE,
                                   showticklabels = FALSE,
                                   zeroline = FALSE,
                                   domain = c(0.15, 1)),
                      yaxis = list(title = "",
                                   showgrid = FALSE,
                                   showline = FALSE,
                                   showticklabels = FALSE,
                                   zeroline = FALSE),
                      barmode = 'stack',
                      paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)', plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)',
                      margin = list(l = 120, r = 10, t = 140, b = 80),
                      showlegend = FALSE) 
# labeling the y-axis
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'paper', yref = 'y', x = 0.14, y = y,
                               xanchor = 'right',
                               text = y,
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE, align = 'right') 
# labeling the percentages of each bar (x_axis)
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 / 2, y = y,
                               text = paste0("<b>", data[,"x1"],'%', "</b>"),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE) 
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 + x2 / 2, y = y,
                               text = paste0("<b>", data[,"x2"],'%', "</b>"),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE) 
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 + x2 + x3 / 2, y = y,
                               text = paste0("<b>", data[,"x3"],'%', "</b>"),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE) 
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 / 2, y = y,
                               text = paste0("<b>", data[,"x4"],'%', "</b>"),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE) 
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 / 2, y = y,
                               text = paste0("<b>", data[,"x5"],'%', "</b>"),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE) 
# labeling the first Likert scale (on the top)
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'paper',
                               x = c(21 / 2, 21 + 30 / 2, 21 + 30 + 21 / 2, 21 + 30 + 21 + 16 / 2,
                                     21 + 30 + 21 + 16 + 12 / 2),
                               y = 1.15,
                               text = top_labels,
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE)

fig
```

I tried this but it didn't work, it makes all the elements of the list disappear from the plot if there is only one zero in the list, I only try to make the 0's not appear and to leave the other elements of the list

```
for (i in 1:length(x1)) {
    fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                                   x = x1 / 2, y = y,
                                   text = paste0("<b>", if(data[i,"x1"] != 0) data[i,"x1"], else [] ,'%', "</b>"),
                                   font = list(family = 'calibri', size = 12,
                                               color = 'black'),
                                   showarrow = FALSE)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a factor that has 0 occurrences at one level.?

If so a workaround might be to just remove that specific level before plotting the variables

```
#Create factor variable with 0 occurrences of one level
dta <- data.frame(
  group <- as.factor(sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 50, replace = TRUE))
)
dta$group <- factor(dta$group, levels = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))

#Drop the level with 0 occurrences
dta$group <- factor(dta$group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to conditionally hiding text in `add_annotations` is to write a custom function. This will check the numeric value to be shown; if it is greater than zero, show the text; otherwise show an empty character value. I left in the HTML tags for completeness.

```
custom_text <- function(data) {
  ifelse(
    data > 0,
    paste0("<b>", data,'%', "</b>"),
    "<b></b>"
  ) 
}
```

Then, in your other `add_annotations` statements, call this custom function. Here is an example:

```
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                               x = x1 / 2, y = y,
                               text = custom_text(data[,"x1"]),
                               font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                                           color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                               showarrow = FALSE)
```

You could do something similar for your other `add_annotations` statements.